# Hide specific category tag on single post page

Tags: categories, tags

I have a category called "Featured", but I don't want this category tag to be shown at the bottom of single post pages. I do want to display the other category tags. How do I hide the tag for this one category?

Answer (score 0):

For specifically post categories, you can use [get_the_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_categories/) filter hook to remove certain found category (term).

```
function filter_get_the_category( $categories, $post_id ) {
  // loop post categories
  foreach ($categories as $index => $category) {
    // check for certain category, you could also check for $term->slug or $term->term_id
    if ( 'Featured' === $category->name ) {
      // remove it from the array
      unset( $categories[$index] );
    }
  }
  return $categories;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_categories', 'filter_get_the_category', 10, 2 );
```

To filter any taxonomy terms, you can use [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_terms/) hook.

```
function filter_get_the_terms( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
  // target certain taxonomy
  if ( 'category' === $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    // loop found terms
    foreach ($terms as $index => $term) {
      // check for certain term, you could also check for $term->slug or $term->term_id
      if ( 'Featured' === $term->name ) {
        // remove it from the array
        unset( $terms[$index] );
      }
    }
  }
  return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'filter_get_the_terms', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go with this simple solution

```
if ( in_category('featured') ) {
}else{
    entry_meta(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the code above but to no avail. How can i hide Company News categories when accessing posts related to CSR events category? Please see page link below:
https://www.mi-eq.com/blood-donation-compaign/